# Ajax data in php, sanitize a number

Tags: php, json, jquery

Im having difficulties sanitizing my data in ajax.php. Here is the code of my js.js:

```
$('.vote_pagelink').click(function() {
var aid = this.id;

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'http://localhost/lr/ajax.php',
       data: "voteid=" + aid + "&tid=" + config.topic_id,  
             success: function(data){
             var test= data;
             alert( "Data Saved: " + test);
          },
                      error: function(data){
              alert( "error: ");
       }               
     });
return false;
});
```

and my ajax.php:

```
$post = $_POST;
if ( ctype_digit(json_encode($post['tid']))) {                              
echo json_encode($post['tid']);
}
```

Why wont this work? Is there any "hidden" data? If I delete the if-condition, it alerts out just a number.

Comment: If you are replying with a JSON object you first need to set the response header to "application/json".

Answer (score 2):

just try after removing "json_encode"-

Because after encoding it will be not number so it will return false;

```
$post = $_POST;
if ( ctype_digit($post['tid'])) {
echo json_encode($post['tid']);
}
```

Comment: Thats what I tried in the first place. The data returned/alerted is just : "Data saved: undefined".

Answer (score 0):

The  [ctype_digit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) function checks if all the characters in a string are numeric or not. When you [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) a value, it returns the json representation of the value. For example:

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
//produces the output
 {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

So you can not really use the ctype_digit on a json_encoded representation. Rather your code should be of the form :

```
ctype_digit($post['tid'])
```